# Loop with some dynamic data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
variable = 5110
for Loop here:
    #should run 6 times
```

I want to run the `for` loop according to the value of `variable` (which comes from user input).
Basically, I want to run one loop for every 1000 units in `variable`.

```
if the data is:
    1000 : loop 1 time 
    2000 : loop 2 times
    3000 : loop 3 times
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from math import ceil

variable = 5110

for i in range(int(ceil(variable / 1000))):
    print(i)
```

**output**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, there's a tricky way to do this without using floating-point arithmetic:

```
for i in range(-(-variable // 1000)):
    print(i)
```

Do you see why it works?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. I used `math.ceil` to round the value to the next higher value.

```
import math

inp = float(raw_input("enter value : "))

i = int(math.ceil(inp / 1000))

for f in range(0,i):
    print f
```